# Cheerio get text from non-unique HTML class (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape information from a website with the following HTML format:

```
<tr class="odd">
<td class="">    <table class="inline-table">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <img src="https://img.a.transfermarkt.technology/portrait/medium/881116-1664480529.jpg?lm=1" data-src="https://img.a.transfermarkt.technology/portrait/medium/881116-1664480529.jpg?lm=1" title="Darío Osorio" alt="Darío Osorio" class="bilderrahmen-fixed lazy entered loaded" data-ll-status="loaded">            </td>
            <td class="hauptlink">
                <a title="Darío Osorio" href="/dario-osorio/profil/spieler/881116">Darío Osorio</a>                            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Right Winger</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</td><td class="zentriert">18</td><td class="zentriert"><img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/flagge/verysmall/33.png?lm=1520611569" title="Chile" alt="Chile" class="flaggenrahmen"></td><td class=""><table class="inline-table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a title="Club Universidad de Chile" href="/club-universidad-de-chile/startseite/verein/1037"><img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/tiny/1037.png?lm=1420190110" title="Club Universidad de Chile" alt="Club Universidad de Chile" class="tiny_wappen"></a>       </td>
        <td class="hauptlink">
            <a title="Club Universidad de Chile" href="/club-universidad-de-chile/startseite/verein/1037">U. de Chile</a>       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/flagge/tiny/33.png?lm=1520611569" title="Chile" alt="Chile" class="flaggenrahmen"> <a title="Primera División" href="/primera-division-de-chile/transfers/wettbewerb/CLPD">Primera División</a>        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</td><td class=""><table class="inline-table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a title="Newcastle United" href="/newcastle-united/startseite/verein/762"><img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/wappen/tiny/762.png?lm=1472921161" title="Newcastle United" alt="Newcastle United" class="tiny_wappen"></a>     </td>
        <td class="hauptlink">
            <a title="Newcastle United" href="/newcastle-united/startseite/verein/762">Newcastle</a>        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/flagge/verysmall/189.png?lm=1520611569" title="England" alt="England" class="flaggenrahmen"> <a title="Premier League" href="/premier-league/transfers/wettbewerb/GB1">Premier League</a>      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</td><td class="rechts">-</td><td class="rechts">€3.00m</td><td class="rechts hauptlink">? </td><td class="zentriert hauptlink"><a title="Darío Osorio to Newcastle United?" id="27730/Newcastle United sent scouts to Chile to follow Dario Osorio. the 18-year-old is being monitored by Barcelona, ​​Wolverhampton and Newcastle United./http://www.90min.com//16127/180/Darío Osorio to Newcastle United?" class="icons_sprite icon-pinnwand-sprechblase sprechblase-wechselwahrscheinlichkeit" href="https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/dario-osorio-to-newcastle-united-/thread/forum/180/thread_id/16127/post_id/27730#27730">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td></tr>
```

I want to scrape "Darió Osorio", "U. de Chile" and "Newcastle" all from the text of different elements with [class="hauptlink"] from the HTML.

I have tried a couple of different things, my most recent attempt looks like this:

```
$('.odd', html).each((index, el) => {
                const source = $(el)
                const information= source.find('td.main-link').first().text().trim()
                const differentInformation= source.find('a:nth-child(1)').text()
            })
```

But I am only successful in scraping "Darió Osorio" with the first()-method. The variable for "differentInformation" currently looks like this with my code: "Darió OsorioU. de ChileNewcastle".
The result I want to get in the end is a JSON-Object like this:

```
[ 
{ "firstInfo" : "Darió Osorio",
 "secondInfo": "U. de Chile",
 "thirdInfo": "Newcastle"
 },
 { "firstInfo" : "Information",
 "secondInfo": "Different Information",
 "thirdInfo": "More Different Information" 
} 
]
```

Comment: Is there a problem with `[...$(".odd .main-link > a")].map(e => e.nodeValue)`? When posting HTML fragments, take care not to oversimplify. What's up with the `.odd` bit--are there multiple of these elements, and if so, should they be grouped somehow? What final output format do you expect, exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on the code snippet? I don't quite understand what it is doing.

Yes, there are multiple .odd classes, and I want to get all of them. The format I am looking for would be a json like this:

´´´
[
{
"firstInfo" : "Information",
"secondInfo": "Different Information",
"thirdInfo": "More Different Information"
},
{
"firstInfo" : "Information",
"secondInfo": "Different Information",
"thirdInfo": "More Different Information"
}
]
´´´

Comment: The selector extracts the text from all `a` elements that are immediate children of `.main-link` elements that are contained within `.odd` elements. Can you confirm that it works for you, and if not, why not? Should the odd elements be grouped somehow?

Comment: `<td class>` looks weird--where's the class value? Also, it's rather odd to have nested `<td>`s if I'm not mistaken. You can [edit] the post to clarify your requirements, the actual HTML and the desired output structure. You might want to validate the HTML at https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea to make sure you copied it correctly. Some sites do have invalid HTML but this is pretty off, so you should confirm that the site's HTML is in fact quite borked so it doesn't look like a mistake on your part.

Comment: I editted my post and included the actual HTML of the website. It is very convoluted. I am still not quite sure how to implement your code snippet. Sorry I am new to cheerio/web scraping.

Comment: Thanks. Can you post a link to the site? The HTML is still sort of a wreck, starting with a `<tr>` out of nowhere. Can you find some top-level HTML element and copy its `innerHTML` in full?

Comment: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/geruechte/neuequellengeruechte/statistik

Comment: Great, thanks. Are you sure you don't want `.even` rows in this table as well?

Comment: I do, i just left it out of my question so i dont unnecessarily bloat my post. I am able to successfully get both .odd and .even with this:
$('.odd, .even', html).each((index, el) => {
            })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification in the comments, it sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "YOUR URL";

(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }

  const html = await response.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  const data = [...$(".items .odd, .items .even")].map(e => {
    const [player, currentClub, interestedClub] =
      [...$(e).find(".hauptlink")].map(e => $(e).text().trim());
    return {player, currentClub, interestedClub};
  });
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This relies on `.hauptlink` which exists in the first 3 row cells that you're interested in retrieving, so that seems like the most straightforward solution. Perhaps a more robust solution would be to pick specific the `<td>` cells out you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly. And I'm not familiar with the way you are interacting with the HTML.
Still, it looks to me like you could just use an [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors) to get the correct elements directly.
So if you want to find all the elements with the `title="information"` it would look something like this (like I said I don't know cheerio so I couldn't test it)

```
$('.odd', html).each((index, el) => {
            const source = $(el)
            const allInformation = source.find('[title="information"]');
            allInformation.each((idx, information) => {
                console.log(information.text().trim();
            })
        })
```

Edit:
Now that I'm thinking more about this you don't even need to change your query. Just don't use the `first()` and instead loop over your result as I did above. Since your query returns you an array (which is why you can do `first()` to get the first element of the said array).
That array should contain all elements matching your query.

Comment: Sorry, bad job writing down the HTML by me. The class is not "information" for all 3 elements, it is "information" for the first, "different information" for the second and "more different information" for the third. So the class is identical to the element's text. Will edit it in my question.

Comment: Ok, but then my edit should still work, instead of going for the first element by `.first().text().trim()` do a loop on the result and then `.text.trim()` on the element in the loop